# Cannot insert NULL into column 'Type'

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, pyodbc

I'm attempting to add a row with two pieces of information to the Notes table. I'm executing the following `INSERT` statement with python.

```
cursor.execute("insert into Notes(Notes, NumericKey) values (?, ?)",Tracking, OrderNumber)
```

The error I'm getting it

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
 IntegrityError: ('23000', "[23000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Type', table 'beltoutlet.dbo.Notes'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. (515) (SQLExecDirectW); [01000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated. (3621)")
```

I'm seeing a lot of people with similar issues but all the attempted solutions haven't helped. I'm at my wits end since for Tracking and OrderNumber both have real values and I dont have a column "Type". Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `Notes` table must have a `NOT NULL` column named `Type`.  Since you aren't including the `Type` column in your insert, the inserted value defaults to `NULL`, hence the error.

Comment: Maybe you have another database or schema with a `Notes` table, but `beltoutlet.dbo.Notes` definitely has a `Type` column.

Comment: To elaborate on what @AaronDietz said, when you execute your query the default *catalog* (database) is "beltoutlet" and the default *schema* is "dbo". If those values are correct then the most likely cause of the issue is that you aren't connected to the SQL Server *instance* you think you are (i.e., one with a `beltoutlet.dbo.Notes` table that really does have a `Type` column that is NOT NULL).

Comment: Thanks guys. I do have two databases but I specify it earlier in the script with `db = pyodbc.connect("DSN=beltoutletsql;UID=beltoutlet;PWD=something")` and `cursor = db.cursor()`

Comment: oh wow. Yes there is a Type column. Its before the key value and I must've been over looking it. That was silly. Thank you very much guys. I just did `cursor.execute("insert into Notes(Type, Notes, NumericKey) values (?, ?, ?)", ' ',Tracking, OrderNumber)` and it finally worked. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Aaron Dietz's comments that the table being referenced (which is not necessarily the table that you want to reference) has a Type column. To remedy the situation, I believe you have two options:

1) Specific the exact table using the database and schema names

```
cursor.execute("insert into [databaseName].[SchemaName].[Notes](Notes, NumericKey) values (?, ?)",Tracking, OrderNumber)
```

2) (Not recommended) Force the insert by putting it a false value (like empty string)

```
cursor.execute("insert into Notes(Notes, NumericKey, [Type]) values (?, ?, ?)",Tracking, OrderNumber, '')
```

Hope this helps.